# How do I install Commerce Kickstart as a Aegir installation profile

Tags: distributions, commerce, aegir

I have been trying to get the most recent version of Commerce Kickstart to install as a profile in Aegir, but I have had no luck. I found the following [note](http://community.aegirproject.org/content/commerce-kickstart-v2-dont-seem-play-nice-aegir-yet) on the Aegir project site, and this [note](http://drupal.org/node/1749990) in the Commerce Kickstart issue queue. Has anyone gotten this to work?

Comment: Kickstart v2 is not Aegir friendly right now. This means it always installs the demo store, which is not suitable for new (non-demo) sites.

Fixing this is planned at one point (by exposing Kickstart specific settings in the "Create site" form, for example), but it might take a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download the .tar.gz from http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/commerce_kickstart-7.x-2.0-rc4-core.tar.gz into your platforms directory on aegir, untar it, and then create a platform with the same name you can build sites using the commerce kickstart profile with aegir.  Here are the commands I used:

```
cd /var/aegir/platforms
curl -O http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/commerce_kickstart-7.x-2.0-rc4-core.tar.gz
tar xzf commerce_kickstart_7.x-2.0-rc4-core.tar.gz
mv commerce_kickstart_7.x-2.0-rc4 commerce-kickstart
chown -Rf aegir\: commerce-kickstart
```

Then go into Aegir and create a platform.  Set the platform directory to this commerce-kickstart directory and don't include a build file.  It'll verify the platform and then you'll be able to create sites on there using the Commerce Kickstart installation profile.

Cheers,
Diwant

Comment: But if I understand correctly If you download the .tar.gz from http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/commerce_kickstart->7.x-2.0-rc4-core.tar.gz into your platforms directory on aegir, untar it, and then create a platform with the same name you can build sites using the commerce kickstart profile with aegir. Here are the commands I used: This will only enable you to create sites that are "Demo Store" sites. This will end up totally screwing you if you try to make a "Live" site.